# Where to find I bit and how to edit it to enable interrupts in ARM Cortex-M4

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, cortex-m

In ARM Cortex-M4F MCU (TM4C1294NCPDT specifically), to deal with interrupts (GPIO interrupts), one of the steps to get the interrupts working is to clear the I BIT.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any useful information about that, could anybody please tell me where to find that bit exactly and how to edit it if I need some special procedures?

And that will be great if I have been told where to find that information exactly after the explanation please (to learn how to answer myself on any other questions).

Comment: The data sheet for the device has documentation on how to program the GPIOs.. It also has some information on the NVIC (the main interrupt controller): http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c1294ncpdt.pdf Also, you may want to look at "Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M4" by Joseph Yiu which is a pretty readable guide to the Cortex ARM CPUs.  Of course, the ultimate references are the ARM Architecture Reference Manuals, which can be downloaded from ARM's website: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0403e.b/index.html

Comment: There is also a [generic programmer's guide for Cortex-M4 cores](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/index.html) which may be useful. In addition, it seems like there might be some confusion here - "the I bit" sounds like it's referring to the CPSR of the 'classic' and A/R-class architectures, whereas on M-class the PRIMASK register does the equivalent job. Either way, in many situations it's simpler to use the `cps` instruction rather than poke registers directly.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Actually I searched inside them all, but not in The Definitive guide to the ARM Cortex-M4, may be I didn't know how to search correctly. could you guide me please where can I exactly find the answer of my question there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the easiest answer for my question is:

To use " `CPSID I`" or " `CPSIE I`" inline assembly code which will set or clear the PRIMASK (I) Bit respectively. (of course that will work just in privileged mode).

And both assembly instructions are equivalent to `__disable_irq()` and `__enable_irq()` functions in CMSIS respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The [CMSIS](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard.php) provides a standard cross-vendor software interface to Cortex-M based devices.  The CMSIS defines a number of [functions for interacting with the NVIC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABEDCBC.html) and PRIMASK including the intrinsics `__disable_irq()`/`__enable_irq()`

Comment: I was watching a video, and what I actually understood is that I have two options to enable the interrupts:
1. is to use the function ins CMSIS which you mentioned.
2. is to use EN register and enable the corresponding bit.

And I am free to use any one I want, is that right? and when yes, what is the difference between them? and then what is the role actually of I bit?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin : As mentioned in the link I gave, there is no differene. An *intrinsic* fiction is one that wraps a processor specific operation that cannot be performed directly in C and avoids the need for assembler code.  If you look at the definition of these functions in the header file, I believe that they are simply inline assembly of the CPSIE/D instructions.

Comment: OK, the easiest answer for my question is:

To use " CPSID I" or " CPSIE I" inline assembly code which will set or clear the PRIMASK (I) Bit respectively. (of course that will work just in privileged mode).

And both assembly instructions are equivalent to __disable_irq() and __enable_irq() functions in CMSIS respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The ARM Cortex-M interrupt system is quite complicated and very well thought. It consists of CPU registers and a tightly coupled interrupt controller (NVIC). Interrupts are prioritized and vectored. There is no single interrupt-enable flag as for smaller 8/16 bit MCUs.

For each interrupt, there are two ARM-core instances to gate the event to the CPU: The CPU `PRIMASK` register (single bit), which can be seen most similar to the classical interrupt-enable flag. Second is one enable bit in the NVIC. For these, there is an ARM standard in the `CMSIS` headers. These provide functions `__enable_irq()` and `__disable_irq()` for the PRIMASK bit. The peripheral interrupt itself has to be controlled by `NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn)` where `IRQn` is the interrupt number as defined in the MCU-specific header file.

Finally, there are most times also interrupt enable bits in each peripheral module as know by the smaller MCUs.

Note that to have an interrupt pass through **all** gates have to be open (all bits set to "enable"). Use the CMSIS functions to manipuate the bits. They very likely will not take more instructions than a hand-crafted version.

**Edit:**

There is no actual need to fiddle yourself with assembler or the registers. Just use the CMSIS functions, you can very likely not do better yourself, but possibly worse. That's actually the intention of CMSIS.

**(end edit)**

Start reading in the reference manual for the MCU and the vendor's homepage. That should provide references and app-notes for the device. You also should read the technical reference manual, architecture reference manual from ARM. Actually, just have a close look at all related documents there for the CPU (M4 for you). These are for free, some require registering.

For the NVIC, you should not access it directly, but using the CMSIS header files as provided by TI for exactly this MCU (the headers require some device-specific settings). If not available,you can get them from ARM, but have to provide the device-specific settings yourself (they are few and are given in the MCU's reference manual).

As the ARM Cortex-M4 has multiple interrupts, you need their symbolic names to enable/disable. These have to be defined in the MCU header which defines all peripheral modules, too (there might be multiple such headers). The names end with `_IRQn`, just search for that.

To use the Cortex-M4 you should read the documents given, or you can try with a good book. However, as this is no tutorial site, nor is it allowed to recommend books, please search yourself.

Comment: Actually I spent yesterday searching online and reading the datasheet, but I couldn't find any useful info, could you help me more sir to get what I need?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: My answer does contain enough information for a start..Please understand this is no tutorial site. If you have any specific question, you are welcome, however.

Comment: Also each GPIO can be individually set to interrupt or not. For the information on that you have to go to the TM4C1294NCPDT datasheet.

Comment: @MichaelBurr My problem is not with the interrupt of GPIO itselt, the problem is till now still just with the I bit.

Comment: It is in fact possible to globally enable/disable interrupts via a single flag the `CPSIE I` and `CPSID I` instructions (and the `__disable_irq()`/`__enable_irq()` CMSIS intrinsics)

Comment: @Olaf
I was watching a video, and what I actually understood is that I have two options to enable the interrupts:
1. is to use the function ins CMSIS which you mentioned.
2. is to use EN register and enable the corresponding bit.

And I am free to use any one I want, is that right? and when yes, what is the difference between them? and then what is the role actually of I bit?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for that, may I ask you why I shouldn't access that NVIC directly? that is actually what I want to know, what does the CMSIS do and I don't know about to deal with interrupts?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: Why do you want to fiddle yourself with bits here? For the "how": Just read the headers. It's all plain text.

Comment: @Olaf : I am not sure what your point is; what else would you expect the PRIMASK EN flag to do, and how does that differ from classic ARM where there was typically a vendor defined interrupt controller that worked much like the NVIC?  I cannot see why you would not want exactly this behaviour.

Comment: @Clifford: According to his comment comment about the video, the OP was not sure if the enable-bits in NVIC and CPU have to be enabled both, or just one of them. So he seems to be not familar with other ARM designs, but likely more with smaller MCUs without vector-interrupts (also according to his question). For older ARMs you are of course right about the enable-flags.

Comment: @Olaf : Maybe, but that is not how I read it;  I assumed he was referring to the difference between the assembler  `CPSIE I` and the intrinsic `__enable_irq()` - when there is no difference.  The original question was *only* about the modifying the "I bit" - which I think is a throwback to the CPSR register I bit on earlier ARM architectures. If he has another *different* question; he should post a new question.

Comment: @Clifford: You might be right. I just had already some people coming from AVR or MSP430 who were confused ARM interrupt controllers add another gating instance. That likely influenced my interpretation.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: Sorry, I seem to have your comments missinterpreted. As stated, just use the intrinsics; these use a special aseembler instruction, you cannot do better yourself - but possibly worse. I cleaned up my comments a bit,

Comment: @Olaf thanks alot. Actually that is exactlly what I was yesterday reading, I read that this assembly instruction need to be excuted in privileged mode, does that instruction do that itself(changing the mode), or should I do that in some way? I think I need to read more about running modes.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: Just think about the idea to have a protected/priviledged execution environment, and if enabling/disabling interrupts is critical. Then think if it makes sense to have an instruction which has to be executed in priviledged mode to change to this mode itself. Sidenote: ARM starts in priviledged mode out of reset. So, if you do not change that, you are very likely in that mode all the time. So much for tutoring. If you have a specific question, open up a new one. Please understand this is no tutorial site!